# Creating nested multistep form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Nested flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN6Av.jpg)

I need some help design nested multistep form. I have implemented it with a naive solution for tracking the step number, looking for a way to abstract and improve the architecture.

Currently, I have two states the currentStep and the currentSubStep. These are the handlers for back and continue.

```
const handleNext = () => {
    const subSteps = steps?.[currentStep]?.subSteps;
    if (currentStep === steps?.length - 1) {
      return;
    }
    if (currentSubStep === subSteps?.length - 1) {
      // move to the next step
      setCurrentStep((prev) => prev + 1);
      setCurrentSubStep(0);
    } else {
      // move to the next
      setCurrentSubStep((prev) => prev + 1);
    }
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    const subSteps = steps?.[currentStep]?.subSteps;
    if (currentStep === 0) {
      if (currentSubStep !== 0) {
        setCurrentSubStep((prev) => prev - 1);
      } else if (currentSubStep === 0) {
        setCurrentSubStep(0);
      } else {
        setCurrentStep((prev) => prev - 1);
      }
    } else {
      if (currentSubStep !== 0) {
        setCurrentSubStep((prev) => prev - 1);
      } else {
        setCurrentStep((prev) => prev - 1);
        setCurrentSubStep(subSteps?.length - 1 || 0);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: May you find this solution useful: https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_step_form/

Comment: This is good for a non-nested steps. In this case I have sections which collapse after the substeps are done. I need to track the substeps progress and then move to the next section's first substeps when the section is done